# Code-First EF4.1 + SQL Server CE4 + Sync Framework

Tags: sql-server, ef-code-first, microsoft-sync-framework, ef4-code-only

Is it possible to use CF EF4.1, SQL Server Compact 4 and Microsoft Sync Framework together?

As I got, MS Sync Framework needs SQL Server compact 3.5, but EF4.1 use SQL Server Compact 4...

**UPDATE**
Ok, I see that it's not possible to sync mssql ce4 using microsoft sync framework. *So Is it possible to use mssql ce3.5 as a storage for entity framework 4.1?*

Answer (score 6):

Sync Framework works directly against the databases using its providers and going thru EF is not supported out of the box. The same goes with Sql Compact 4 (see [Scenarios not enabled by Sql Compact 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx)

Comment: The Idea is to use EF 4.1 and MSSQL Compact and Replicate this database using sync framework with server database (e.g. mssql 2008r2). So then I switch EF4.1 connection to mssql compact 3.5 I got the error: Unable to determine the provider name for connection of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection'.

Answer (score 2):

Won't work - see [this page with limitations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx) that apply to SQL Server CE 4 for now:

> *Data replication with SQL Server:
>   Compact 4.0 **does not support** data
>   replication with SQL Server using **Sync
>   Framework**, merge replication or remote
>   data access (RDA).*

Comment: but is it possible to make ef4.1 code-first to work with mssql ce 3.5? Because Sync Framework works just fine with mssql ce3.5

Answer (score 2):

SQL CE 3.5 does not work with the Code First approach (the provider doesn't support DDL generation); however it should work just fine using the Model First or Database First approaches of EF 4.1.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, it is possible** - if you do not rely on the creation or migration features (EF 5.0).

So, first configure EF to use the SQL CE provider using the app.config and a named configuration

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestDatabase"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"
         connectionString="Data Source=test.sdf"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and

```
public class TestDbDataContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDbDataContext() : base("TestDatabase") { }
}
```

disable the creation and migration functionality before you use your data context

```
Database.SetInitializer<TestDbDataContext>(null);
```

Now you can access the database. Obviously you will have to create the tables manually.

**Caveat:**

Inserting server generated keys does not work with CE 3.5. So you will have to manage them on the client side (best use GUIDs to prevent key conflicts). Furthermore, even if you plan to manage the keys yourself you need to watch out. Defining the key like this

```
[Key]
Guid Id { get; set; }
```

will lead EF to believe that the key is generated on the server side. Therefore, you need to define the key properties using EF's fluent API to set the `DatabaseGeneratedOption` to None:

```
this.Property(p => p.ProductId)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)
    .IsRequired();

this.HasKey(p => p.ProductId);
```

This can be either done in a configuration class (as in the sample) or in the data contex's `OnModelCreating` function.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/9bc99e3c-a6e6-4439-8aec-40a7cae6c2a3/), SQL Server Compact 3.5 cannot be used with Entity Framework 4.1 Code First provider. It can be used with EF 4.1 Model First or Database First.